# Delete records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Consider these several tables:

```
tab1
-------
userid
email
address
environment

tab2

-------
ecode
company
policy

tab3
-------
id
pan no.
dl no.
```

Here `tab1` is the parent table. I want to delete all the `userid` of `tab1` from `tab2` and `tab3`. Either `userid` will be in `tab1` or `tab2` or both. These tables are environment specific means `environment/tab1` and `environment/tab2`.

How can this be done with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert with the AS400, but I don't know of any way to do that in any SQL dialect. You need to start a transaction, perform your separate deletes, then commit the transaction if you want to make sure that it the action is atomic (meaning that the whole thing runs or none of it runs).

The code would probably look something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM tab2
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM tab1)

DELETE FROM tab3
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM tab1)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

You don't specify exactly how those tables are related, so I took a guess. Also, you should probably have some error handling that issues a `ROLLBACK` if an error is encountered. I don't know the error handling syntax for AS400 (DB2?), so you'll need to look that up.

Comment: ok...can you please suggest me how I do everything, so I not need think ever again?

Answer (score 0):

Are the environments on the same machine? If not you might want to look at DDM files.
See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fddm%2Frbae5exiseries.htm).